# How to get average of a salary at the same time LPAD the out put with '-'

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate the average salary from the employee table and LPAD the answer at the same time. I am using Oracle SQL. for example I want the output to be ---346 or --5678

Comment: post a [mcve] showing table definition, sample data.

Comment: ---456
--3445
----7
---567
I want it to be displayed like this

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) Also see [ask].

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, @mina! The other comments are prompting you to give the information needed to (try to) answer your question. Until you provide some sample data, for example, we lack details about your "employee table" necessary to help you. You'll get the hang of posting questions on SO quickly!

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT LPAD(ROUND(AVG(SALARY)), 6, '-')
  FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

should be close to what you need.